# Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to retrieve data from a web page with the following Excel VBA:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object 
Dim oBrowser As Object  

Sub Website_()

Dim oHTML_Element As Object 
Dim sUrl As String

sUrl = "https://www.example.com/"
    
Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
oBrowser.silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.Navigate sUrl
oBrowser.Visible = False

With oBrowser
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Loop
End With

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document.getElementsByClassName("val")

End Sub
```

This opens MS Edge, not IE, and it is visible.

It returns the error:

```
Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed.
```

On row:

```
Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
```

This is on Windows 11, it doesn't have IE, I think. On Windows 10 I have no issues.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the page can no longer be accessed in IE. That's why it opens in Edge. But Edge can't be controlled from VBA, so it doesn't know `Busy`. What happens in the background I can not say. By the way, `Busy` is not a method, it is a property. The IE should not be used anymore. It is dead, deadder, deadest ;-)

Comment: @Zwenn I think the issue is Windows 11 - it does not contain IE anymore. Besides, VBA cannont control Edge. Thus, how to scrape a web page with W11?

Comment: Look into xmlhttp or selenium basic

Comment: xmlhttp is the keyword I was looking for @RaymondWu, thank you!